# Changing co-ordinate systems quadratic forms

Tags: quadratic-forms

A = $$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 4 \\4 & -4\end{bmatrix}$$

and 
$$q(\mathbf{x})= \mathbf{x}\cdot A \mathbf{x}, $$

then what is?

$$q(\mathbf{e_1})=  $$

$$q(\mathbf{e_2})=$$

$$$$
$$$$
$$$$
Im really struggling this this. I have ascertained that $$q(\mathbf{x}) = x^2+8xy-4y^2$$

Also the Eigenvalue

$$λ_1=\frac{\sqrt{89}-3}{2}$$
$$λ_2=\frac{-\sqrt{89}-3}{2}$$

Eigenvectors

$$\begin{bmatrix}\frac{\sqrt{89}+5}{8}\\1\end{bmatrix}$$
$$\begin{bmatrix}\frac{-\sqrt{89}+5}{8}\\1\end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just use the definition?
$$
q(e_1)=e_1\cdot Ae_1=e_1\cdot\begin{pmatrix}1\\4\end{pmatrix}=1
$$
and
$$
q(e_2)=e_2\cdot Ae_2=e_2\cdot\begin{pmatrix}4\\-4\end{pmatrix}=-4.
$$
You don't need the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $A$ to compute the value of the quadratic form at some points.

Otherwise you computed
$$
q(x,y)=x^2+8xy-4y^2.
$$
You can also use this to compute
$$
q(e_1)=q(1,0)=1^2+8\cdot1\cdot0-4\cdot 0^2=1
$$
and
$$
q(e_2)=q(0,1)=0^2+8\cdot 0\cdot 1-4\cdot 1^2=-4.
$$

Comment: Yes was way overthinking that one! 
Cheers